# Circular buffer with threadsafety for swift ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a writer and a reader thread, the writer writes much faster than the reader.
I'm looking for a thread-safe implementation of Circular Queue in swift
Does someone has any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific needs you can always just build one yourself, it's not too difficult to implement a circular queue. For the threadsafety I suggest creating an `NSOperationQueue`, setting `maxConcurrentOperations` to 1 and to schedule a get/set task to only this queue, this way there can't be any conflicts.